# Issues with executing Servlet Events

Tags: java, servlets, servletcontextlistener

I have created the listener class as,

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Context Initialized");
    }
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Context Destroyed");
    }
}
```

my welcome page is a servlet as follows,

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class WelcomeContextListener extends HttpServlet 
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    }
}
```

I have added the below code in my web.xml file,

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>ContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Now when I run the above web application the following error occurs,

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.awt.HeadlessException. Please see server.log for more details.
The module has not been deployed.

I'm using Netbeans IDE. Any suggestion to help me out in this situation???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't comment on the HeadlessException, but...packages man, for the love of James Gosling, packages.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't use `JOptionPane` in a Servlet context remeber you are in a web enviroment in a server no one will see the message use `System.out.println` and follow the log file or some `log4j` log classes. And on `<listener-class>ContextListener</listener-class>` should be entire package `<listener-class>com.blahsomething.ContextListener</listener-class>`

Comment: @WillHartung hey man the 'ContextListener' class is in the default packege so what should be the package path? Pardon my naive knowledge and my sincere appology to 'Lord James Gosling' ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't use `JOptionPane` in a Servlet context remeber you are in a web enviroment in a server no one will see the message use `System.out.println` and follow the log file or some log4j log classes.

And on

`<listener-class>ContextListener</listener-class>`

should be entire package

`<listener-class>com.blahsomething.ContextListener</listener-class>`

And for the `java.awt.HeadlessException`

Add this to your tomcat startup parameters

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

To configure a server on Netbeans IDE, if I recall it right, it should be on

```
Tools -> Servers
```

Inside it you will find a Startup tab, there you can configure the parameters.

Comment: My listener class 'ContextListener' is in the default package, so which path should I give? And can you tell me how to set the startup parameters you mentioned in netbeans IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Most of servlet containers work in awt/swing headless mode. In this mode many awt/swing components do not work, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html.